# Why is Far Cry 3 Z93 sniper not visible in shop?

Tags: far-cry-3

I started playing far cry and in the weapons shop I don't see the Z93 .50 cal sniper.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It unlock when you reach the second island. You can also unlock the signature version when you find 20 relics that fires explosive rounds.

Comment: you can also find it in the mission where you help the rakyat defend against an ambush from the top of a water tower(z93 is at the top of the tower),  I'm not sure whether it'll be there after the mission.

Comment: Its there after the mission and I kept it :)

Answer (score 1):

You can keep it after that ambush mission. Just keep it equipped, because it won't be available to equip again until you unlock it and it appears in the shop.